# How do I enable xdebug in rasmus/php7dev to use phpunit with coverage?

Tags: phpunit, vagrant, code-coverage, xdebug, php-7

## Environment

I've setup a Vagrant with:

```
config.vm.box = "rasmus/php7dev"
```

I've got this in my composer:

```
"require-dev":
{
    "phpunit/phpunit": "5.3.*"
}
```

I used to use `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"` as the distro, but as this phpunit requirement conflicted with the PHP version I desired to go with PHP7. I tried `config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"` with no luck, this is why I decided for `"rasmus/php7dev"` but I may change the box if needed.

## Goes well

When I run this command `vendor/bin/phpunit`, everything goes fine:

```
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$ vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..............                                                    14 / 14 (100%)

Time: 276 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (14 tests, 14 assertions)
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$
```

## Fails

Instead, if I try to get the coverage, with this `vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html doc/coverage`, it fails with:

```
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$ vendor/bin/phpunit --coverage-html doc/coverage
PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Error:         No code coverage driver is available

..............                                                    14 / 14 (100%)

Time: 270 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (14 tests, 14 assertions)
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$
```

## Investigation

Seems the problem is because it does not have the xdebug:

```
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$ php -i | grep xdebug
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$
```

But if I look at the xdebug packages I find they are for php5:

```
vagrant@driveway-overshoot-model-ddd-with-symfony:/vagrant$ sudo apt-cache search xdebug
php5-xdebug - Xdebug Module for PHP 5
```

## Question

What should I do { a) manually, b) when provisioning the machine } so I have xdebug in a Vagrant Box that runs PHP7, in order to be able to run phpunit with coverage reporting?

Comment: did you try to configure a Vagrantfile through https://puphpet.com, you can install php v7 with x-debug support and you will not be dependent on someone's else box

Comment: I did know about puphpet time ago but, frankly, I did not think of it this time. Worth pointer. I'll try puphpet in parallel of expecting of more answers here. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: May help: https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/39 | https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/51